# How would one parse an outline where order is retained

Tags: javascript, parsing, outline

I am trying to parse a document that looks something like this...

```
<line>(a) main category</line>
<line>(1) sublime</line>
<line>(i) sub sub line</line>
<line>(b) other category </line>
```

I am not sure how to ensure things like i the roman numeral vs I the letter. This seems like something there should be a library or a pattern for, but I can't seem to find one.

Can anyone think of a pattern? I would like to use js but I am fairly language agnostic.

Comment: Well, the pattern I'm seeing here is that it should be encapsulated with brackets "()" - A simple regex could help you out there

Comment: I agree and I already capture that information. I am worried about order, getting 1 and I connected to the a

Comment: Ah, right. I would define a method that checks "types" so you can see if the level would be the same or deeper - something like; if ('a' is-same-level-as 'i') where the is-same-level would be a method that checks "numeral = same (1, 2, 4 etc.), a.b.c.d.e.f.g. is same, i, ii, iii vi, v iv is same". But you'll run in to trouble as soon a b c gets to h i j k.. Or V.. Or M.. Hmm. Unless you keep track of history - knowing that "i" after "b" should be a level deeper, and "i" after "h" should not be. Do you understand what i mean? Sorry, kinda thoughtfarting here

Comment: Yeah that is the way I was thinking but it just seems like there needs to be a better pattern somewhere. Also I and v still are an issue with any of the creative solutions I have come up with like you say

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each line, and check the current "header" with the previous ones.

Create a method that looks something like this (not valid JS, just pseudocode);

```
function isSameType(last, current) {
    if (typeof last == 'numeric' && typeof current == 'numeric') { 
        return true; // 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.
    }
    if (last == 'a' && current == 'b') { //Improve here ;p
        return true; 
    }
    if (last == 'i' && current == 'ii') {
        return true;
    }
    if (last == 'h' && current == 'i') {
        return true; // This is an edgecase... Most likely I after H is the same type - but it might not be, you'll never know for sure
    }
    return false; //Its not caught - go deepar!
}
```

so with that markup you'll have something that kinda works, but is not completely waterproof...

EDIT: If this is all the information - you just can stop searching because its impossible to know if the I after H is actually a level deeper or not. It just is impossible.

EDIT 2: As long as its in the A -> 1 -> I format, it should work.

```
a.  LEVEL 0
b.  LEVEL 0
c.  LEVEL 0
1.  LEVEL 1
2.  LEVEL 1
i.  LEVEL 2
ii. LEVEL 2
3.  LEVEL 1
i.  LEVEL 2
e.  LEVEL 0 <- this might be an issue - say the letter is V, you wouldn't know if it was level 1 alphabetical or roman (level 2) - Or maybe they went to "a" - in that case its probably level 3, and not level 1, because the A was already there in level 1. A lot of rules!
```

With the right set of rules you'll get far. But if they jump from level 3 (iv) to level 1 (v) you might run in to trouble. But so far, if you see "v", and the previous level was numeric (3), then its bound to be roman.

Comment: Unfortunately the real data has plenty of i(s)

Comment: Hmm, as long as the nesting goes from A -> 1 -> I, then you can figure it out for sure. That means that I after A is _never_ deeper, because there should be a numeric level in between.

Comment: I guess that would be true hmmm didn't think of it that way

Comment: I think we will have an issue still for example (h)(1)(i)(2)(i)(1) stuff like this would still be a problem

Comment: yeah there is no guarantee that there is an i so it could also be (h)(1)(i) and I wouldn't know which one the i was supposed to be (numeral or char). This can be solved by looking forward but if i is the last line it becomes an issue. This is far more complex than it looked on first glance :-)

Answer (score -1):

Catch the content of the line

```
var letter = (line.match(/^\s*\(.{1,2})\)/) || [''])[0]
```

Comment: This doesn't maintain order for example how do I know the 1 goes with a or b

Comment: What do you want exactly ?

Comment: I need to organize it in a way that I have a collection of json object (just for simplicity) that collection in this case would have two items a and b. Inside a there would be an object 1 inside 1 there would be an object I and so on. I don't just need the indicator as you have done here

Comment: I am working on the algorithm, but I have a lock of time, I will edit my answer soon